# Convert simple iPhone app to Universal app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, universal

I have very simple iPhone app, which uses just `UIButtons`, `UIlabels`, `UITableView`. without any custom controllers and graphics. How can I convert app to universal with that UI?

Comment: what do you mean by Universal? iPhone+iPad?

Comment: Yes, of course Universal = iPhone and iPad application

Comment: Just update the target for iPad in the file menu, I believe. You will have to relayout the user interface and really, iPad has a different design paradigm, so you should familiarize yourself with SplitViewController and PopoverController classes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First update the application target device to Universal.

1. Update the application target device to Universal.
2. Check the Info.plist for `NSMainNibFile` & `NSMainNibFile~ipad` keys.
3. For all other views, have two different NIB. For example FirstView.xib & FirstView~ipad.xib. iOS runtime will load the proper view based on the device.

Here is a screenshot of a sample project:
[image: Info.plist for iOS Universal app]

Answer (score 1):

I needed to convert my iPhone App to iPad yesterday and found the easiest way to do it as long as your app is pretty simple.  Mine was literally just some tableViews that were set to auto-size.  In Targets / Devices just change it from 'iPhone' to 'Universal' and then build your application.  This worked very nicely for me.  All tableViews were perfectly formatted for the iPad and that is really all I needed.

Note that if you had any other XIB files that were not just tableViews, such as a window with text fields, all you have to do is set them each to resize properly so they stretch and stay at the top and your simple app should be pretty much all set for the iPad.

Obviously you'll need to test it and tweak anything needed but for the most part the above worked magically for me and took literally one second to convert my iPhone app to an iPad app!