# Creating Universal application from existing iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7, xcode5

I'm developing `iPhone` application which was created on `Xcode` 4.6. Now I'm running same application in `Xcode` 5.0 which works fine for me on `iOS` 7 also. Now I have to create an Universal application from existing application. I have google for it and found 2-3 solutions which talks about creating new `xibs` for `iPad` and change target to universal application. I want to know what is the easiest way to achieve this. My application was created on `Xcode` 4.6 with `xibs` for `iPhone`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861330/convert-simple-iphone-app-to-universal-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838044/converting-an-iphone-nib-to-ipad-nib-in-xcode-5

Comment: @Rushabh I don't think so converting existing xibs to iPad xibs will work.

Comment: you have to use new xib for iPad and change  the application target to universal.this is one of easy solution.

Comment: @Rushabh is there any other way out in Xcode 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a universal app that supported for both iPhone and iPad then the best approach is to use Size classes. You can also customize your layout for a specific device (iPhone/iPad) by using size classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do create new xibs for ipad and use exists xib, but then you need to hope what autoresizing work good. Anyway most often ipad have different design. So, if you want different design you need make him (using new xibs or new code).