# Xcode 7.3 How to Convert my existing iPhone application to universal app, for work with iPad in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Previously, it is only an iPhone application. Now I want it run in iPad as well. So I chose the target as universal, but when I run it in iPad simulator. It only remains the color of the view without any labels and textfields.
[image: General]

How can I make the application run properly both in iPad and iPhone?

Comment: are you using XIB or Storyboard? If XIB then make sure you have iPad compatible XIB, if Storyboard make sure you have configured proper Size Classes (Any x Any recommended).

Comment: check if you are using size classes in main storyboard or not and also if you have configured properly to run your design in iPads also. like @DipenPanchasara said.

Comment: I use Compact x Any to add labels. Now I want to use Any x Any. But there is nothing on that. I use "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes".

Comment: You need to disable Compact x Any constraint from Attribute Inspector, at the end you will see constraint checkbox uncheck wC x hAny and add new constraint of wAny x hAny using + button.

Comment: Hi @DipenPanchasara, can you explain in detail? How to disable Compact x Any constraint from Attribute Inspector?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861330/convert-simple-iphone-app-to-universal-app

Comment: @user6702783 i have added answer check it. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1 :** First You need to change your size Class to **wAny x hAny**. Now when you open your controller all your controls will be visible as disabled, Because you change your size class and constraints defined are not compatible with it.

[image: Controls in different size Class]

**Step 2 :** Now select all your controls in your controller then goto bottom of Attribute Inspector. You will see checkbox for **C x Any**. uncheck it.

[image]

**Step3 :** Now you have to add new Constraint for **Any x Any**. As you have already changed your size class to **Any x Any ** just check above check box which will by default activate constrains for current size class.

[image: Activate current constraints.]

**Step 4 :** Then you need to add missing constraints which ever necessary for your controls.

Comment: I followed all the steps, it works well in iPad now. But why nothing in iPhone now?

Comment: Just remove compact x any constraint for controls in iphone and add Any x Any. You will get the result

Comment: I have removed compact x any constraint for controls in iPhone and add Any x Any, still now not working in iPhone. and its perfectly working in iPad. please suggest.

Comment: have you changed your Size Class for Storyboard/Xib? Make sure any  control refers any other Size Class constraints.

Comment: Yes Dipen, I have changed. Now Im getting iPad and iPhone LandScape mode only, but not iPhone Portrait.

Comment: You are missing something minor or your controls are not aligned to fit in portrait mode. May be you have set constraints for Portrait in iPhone, Check Size Class in iPhone all portrait and verify none of the control is using that constraint, Make sure they only use Any x Any. Last solution is remove all constraints for all controls and assign then new in Any x Any SC.